# While Loop Guessing Number Game - Python

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, jython

I'm trying to make a 'guess the number between 1-10' game but the while loops seems to keep running. I want to program to let the user guess a number then display if its too high or low etc then start again automatically (loop) to allow the user to pick again. This code makes it run forever though.
Can you guys help me?

```
import random

def numberGuess():
  printNow("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 10")
  guess = 0 # give guess a starting value
  randNum = random.randrange(1,11) # this line generates a random number
  guess = int(input("Try to guess the number:")) # ask user for a number
  print randNum 
  while guess != randNum:
    if (guess == randNum): 
      print "You got it!"
    if (guess > randNum):
      print "Wrong! You guessed too high"
    if (guess < randNum):
      print "Wrong! You guessed too low"
```

Comment: You don't change `guess` inside the loop...

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to guess inside the loop

```
  while guess != randNum:
    guess = int(input("Try to guess the number:"))
    if (guess > randNum):
      print "Wrong! You guessed too high"
    if (guess < randNum):
      print "Wrong! You guessed too low"
  print "You got it!"
```

Comment: with this code the first guess will not be evaluated!

Comment: @user3015703, Im only specifying modification for the loop. But `guess` is inputted before calling the loop so it should get evaluated

Answer (score 0):

If you move the `input` statement into the while loop, you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
import random

def numberGuess():
  print("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 10")
  randNum = random.randrange(1,11) # this line generates a random number
  while guess != randNum:
    guess = int(input("Try to guess the number:")) # ask user for a number
    if (guess == randNum): 
      print "You got it!"
    if (guess > randNum):
      print "Wrong! You guessed too high"
    if (guess < randNum):
      print "Wrong! You guessed too low"

numberGuess()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

def numberGuess():
  randNum = random.randrange(1,11) # this line generates a random number
  guess = int(input("Try to guess the number:")) # ask user for a number
  print (randNum)
  while True:
    if (guess == randNum):
        print ("You got it!")
        break
    if (guess > randNum):
        print ("Wrong! You guessed too high")
        guess = int(input("Try to guess the number:"))  # ask user for a number
    if (guess < randNum):
        print ("Wrong! You guessed too low")
        guess = int(input("Try to guess the number:"))  # ask user for a number

numberGuess()
```