# How do I loop a gamequestion script until it is answered correctly? (Python)

Tags: python, loops

```
from random import randint
x=(randint(0,9))
print "I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 10."
y = raw_input("What is your number? (Integer from 1 to 10)")
if y<x:
    print "Too low!"
elif y>x:
    print "Too high!"
elif y==x:
    print "Spot On!"
    sys.exit()
```

How do I loop it so you have to keep guessing until you get the number?

Comment: Related: [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to investigate the `while` loop for that purpose. Please check [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-while-statement) for details and check answers [already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25683715/while-loop-guessing-number-game-python) in place for helpful code sniplets.

Comment: By using a `while` loop, I was able to make it work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just break when you get the correct number

```
from random import randint
x=(randint(0,10))
print "I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 10."
while True:
    y = int(raw_input("What is your number? (Integer from 1 to 10)"))
    if y<x:
        print "Too low!"
        print "Let's try again"
    elif y>x:
        print "Too high!"
        print "Let's try again"
    elif y==x:
        print "Spot On!"
        break
```

Converted y to `int` and if you want to include 10 then you must iterate till 10 not 9 in `randint` function